# Show that optimal TSP followed by optimal clustering can be suboptimal

Tags: graph-theory, optimization, algorithms, operations-research

Consider the classic [Vehicle Routing Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vehicle_routing_problem).

In [this paper](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/John_Beasley/publication/23793206_Route_first--Cluster_second_methods_for_vehicle_routing/links/0fcfd51013de989426000000.pdf), the author shows how to *optimally* partition an *optimal* TSP tour, into feasible routes. In other words he describes a "route-first cluster-second" approach for the problem, where the clustering part is optimal.

On page $2$, it is written:

> Note that it is easily shown that an optimal TSP tour followed by an optimal set of vehicle routes does not necessarily lead to an optimal set of vehicle routes.

I am trying to come up with a very simple example where this is true. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let out graph have $6$ vertices on a plane with Manhattan metric (for simplicity). Vertices are point with following coordinates: $v_1(0, 0), v_2(0, 1), v_3(5, 0), v_4(5, 1), v_5(10, 0), v_6(10, 1)$. Then $v_1v_2v_4v_6v_5v_3v_1$ is the optimal TSP tour. Let $v_1$ be depot and vehicle capacity equals 2. If you partition tour optimally you'll have to visit $v_5$ and $v_6$ by one vechicle (22 units length), $v_4$ and $v_2$ by anothere one (12 units length) and $v_3$ by the third one (10 units length), that is 44 units length in total. Optimal set of vehicle routes is the following: visit $v_5$ and $v_6$ by one vechicle (22 units length), $v_3$ and $v_4$ by another one (12 units length) and $v_2$ by the third one (2 units length), that is 36 units length in total.

Comment: How do you know that you have the optimal partition?

Comment: There are only two partitions possible. The other one has the same total length.

Comment: Given the tour $v_1-v_2-v_4-v_6-v_5-v_3-v_1$, I believe there are more than $2$  feasible partitions, for example the following partition is also feasible:
$v_1-v_2-v_1$, $v_1-v_4-v_1$, $v_1-v_6-v_1$,  $v_1-v_5-v_1$, $v_1-v_3-v_1$
But I think you are right...by inspection it is not difficult to see that the one you have proposed is the best one.